# Does Google Sheets v3 Deprecation impact calls in AppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api, deprecated

I've learned recently that Google Sheets API v3 is being deprecated in favor or v4, and I was wondering if it had any impacts on App Scripts ?

In my AppScripts, I mainly use the `SpreadsheetApp` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app), the API change do not seem to have any impact on that, but I have to be sure, to know if I need to migrate those scripts.

Thank you in advance for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the [Apps Script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference):

> **G Suite services** are services that let you access the data of G Suite products such as Drive, Gmail, Calendar, Docs, Sheets, and others. **These services are separate from APIs created for those products**; in general, G Suite services are easier to use than G Suite APIs, but are optimized for only the most common use cases.

Those are essentially the DriveApp, SpreadsheetApp, DocumentApp classes among others. They are a high-level abstraction of the API, and they are less likely to change (although some minor changes may occur).

> **Advanced Google services** provide the means to use Google APIs (including but not limited to the G Suite product APIs) within Apps Script. **Advanced Google services are really just thin wrappers around those APIs**, and are not an API themselves. For more details, see Advanced Google services.

These include the Drive, Docs, Calendar classes among others. They are a lower-level layer of abstraction compared to the "G suite services", and thus are more likely to change.

Since you are using the high-level abstraction in this case, you probably don't need to worry too much.

You may also want to visit the following links:

- [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration).
- [Apps Script release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases). As you will see here, most of the changes on `SpreadsheetApp` have been on extending its functionality, but not modifying the existing one nor removing features.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought, but you made it real clear !